# fine tuning the == operator to match double percision

Tags: c++, operators, double

In my code there is a parameter I am calculating. During many of the test runs, this parameter should be 0. Since the parameter is calculating through multiple additions and subtractions, it is not exactly 0 but it is less than 10^-10. Currently I am using:

```
double tol = pow(10,-10);
if (fabs(delta_U) < tol)){//whatever
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do so?

Comment: You can't overload operators for native types.

Comment: Besides, `operator==` is generally defined such that `a==b` and `b==c` implies `a==c`. This algorithm doesn't, so you shouldn't hide it behind an innocent-looking name.

Answer (score 4):

It looks fine. You could just write the tolerance directly, instead of computing it with `pow`.

```
double tol = 1e-10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify floating point in scientific notation:

```
if (fabs(delta_U) < 1e-10)
{
   //whatever
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jpalecek is correct - saves computation of a constant.

I do not know the nature of the calculations but you could either possibly

- Reduce the errors by modifying the order of calculations and operators
- Possibly make the calculation use integers

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a function so it is more clear what you are trying to do:

```
if (near_zero(delta_U))
{
   // ...
}
```

where:

```
inline bool near_zero(double d)
{
   return fabs(d) < 1e-10;
}
```